# function returning the output 'None'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can somebody explain to me why in the following code I get 'your answer is None' please?

```
question='should save the notebook after edit?(T/F) :'
correct_ans=('t')

def tf_quiz(question,correct_ans):
    if input(question)==correct_ans:
        print('correct')
    else:
        print('incorrect') 

quiz=tf_quiz(question,correct_ans)

print('your answer is',quiz)
```

output:

```
should save the notebook after edit?(T/F) :t
correct
your answer is None
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function doesn't explicitly return anything, so implicitly it returns `None`. Instead of printing inside the function, just return the value you want:

```
def tf_quiz(question,correct_ans):
    if input(question) == correct_ans:
        return 'correct' # Here
    else:
        return 'incorrect' # And here
```

Answer (score 1):

Because tf_quiz function does not return a value, it only prints it. Use `return 'correct'` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your function "tf_quiz" does not return any output. By default python returns None as the return value of a function, unless it is specified to return something else.
So this is how you should correct your code.

```
question='should save the notebook after edit?(T/F) :'
correct_ans='t'

def tf_quiz(question,correct_ans):
    usr_answer = input(question) 
    if usr_answer==correct_ans:
        print('correct')
    else:
        print('incorrect') 
    return usr_answer

quiz=tf_quiz(question,correct_ans)

print('your answer is',quiz)
```